# Optimal guitar fingerings

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, music-theory

I want to find optimal frettings for guitar scales, played one note at a time. In particular let's assign a metric $d$ that assings a distance between pairs $(s_1,f_1)$, $(s_2,f_2)$ of integer numbers representing string/fret coordinates on the fretboard. Given

- the signature of a scale, which is the list of intervals separating each pair of subsequent notes in the scale
- an initial fret
- an initial string
- a number of consecutive notes per string

What is the complexity of an algorithm that finds all the sequences $(s_1,f_1), \ldots, (s_n,f_n)$ with the property that

- $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} d((s_i,f_i), (s_{i+1},f_{i+1}))$ is minimum
- the initial string and all strings physically below it are among the $s_i$'s
- the prescribed number of consecutive notes per string is respected

What known optimization algorithm could be more easily adapted to solve this problem?

Comment: Your given properties seem to give a deterministic algorithm with only one possible resulting sequence. Perhaps some examples would help to show what you actually mean. For context, it might also be interesting to assess a Segovia scale according to your criteria.

Comment: Ok I understand, I should have relaxed one constraint: the input "number of notes per string" should be replaced by two inputs, i.e. "min notes per string" and "max notes per string"

Answer (score 1):

You can use dynamic programming, as shown for piano by Hart, Bosch and Tsai, [*Finding Optimal Piano Fingerings*](http://web.gps.caltech.edu/~tsai/files/HartBoschTsai_2000.pdf) (2000).  Searching for "dynamic programming" and "guitar fingering" yields several other papers.